# How to change the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I've changed my name on GitHub and try to push my application.
I tried to push after git add and git commit, but it didn't work.
I deleted my repository and now I try to create a new repository, but git doesn't know about my new name:

```
dartnyan@PC:~/Projects/sample_app$ git remote add origin 
https://github.com/NyanTyrrell/sample_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
dartnyan@PC:~/Projects/sample_app$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': NyanTyrrell
Password for 'https://NyanTyrrell@github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/newDartNyan/sample_app.git/' not found
```

How can I change the path from /newDartNyan/ (old name) to /NyanTyrrell/ (new name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the option `set-url` of the `remote` command as such.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/NyanTyrrell/sample_app.git
```

This will change the remote URL to the value provided, in this case `https://github.com/NyanTyrrell/sample_app.git`.